# Facebook Graph API in workplace: group post with mentioning users

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

How do I mention a user in a post in the 2.8 version Graph API in Facebook Workplace?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{group_id}/feed
params: message=test
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{group_id}/feed
```

Parameters: `message=test` and `tag=userid` of the person you want to tag.